# What does `tf.strided_slice()` do?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am wondering what `tf.strided_slice()` operator actually does.
The [doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/array_ops/slicing_and_joining#strided_slice) says,

> To a first order, this operation extracts a slice of size end - begin from a tensor input starting at the location specified by begin. The slice continues by adding stride to the begin index until all dimensions are not less than end. Note that components of stride can be negative, which causes a reverse slice.

And in the sample,

```
# 'input' is [[[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2]],
#             [[3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4]],
#             [[5, 5, 5], [6, 6, 6]]]
tf.slice(input, [1, 0, 0], [2, 1, 3], [1, 1, 1]) ==> [[[3, 3, 3]]]
tf.slice(input, [1, 0, 0], [2, 2, 3], [1, 1, 1]) ==> [[[3, 3, 3],
                                                       [4, 4, 4]]]
tf.slice(input, [1, 1, 0], [2, -1, 3], [1, -1, 1]) ==>[[[4, 4, 4],
                                                        [3, 3, 3]]]
```

So in my understanding of the doc, the first sample (`tf.slice(input, begin=[1, 0, 0], end=[2, 1, 3], strides=[1, 1, 1])`),

- resulting size is `end - begin = [1, 1, 3]`. The sample result shows `[[[3, 3, 3,]]]`, that shape is `[1, 1, 3]`, it seems OK.
- the first element of the result is at `begin = [1, 0, 0]`. The first element of the sample result is `3`, which is `input[1,0,0]`, it seems OK.
- the slice continues by adding stride to the begin index. So the second element of the result should be `input[begin + strides] = input[2, 1, 1] = 6`, but the sample shows the second element is `3`.

What `strided_slice()` does?

(Note: [method names in the samples and the last example is incorrect](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/5761).)

Comment: It doesn't add `strides` directly to `begin`

Comment: @martianwars Thank you for reply! So, what `strides` is used for?

Comment: hang on, writing an answer :)

Comment: The new psuedo code seems to be better, have a look

Comment: The third official example should be: `tf.strided_slice(input, [1, -1, 0], [2, -3, 3], [1, -1, 1])`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The mistake in your argument is the fact that you are directly adding the lists `strides` and `begin` element by element. This will make the function a lot less useful. Instead, it increments the `begin` list one dimension at a time, starting from the last dimension.

Let's solve the first example part by part. `begin = [1, 0, 0]` and `end = [2, 1, 3]`. Also, all the `strides` are `1`. Work your way backwards, from the last dimension.

Start with element `[1,0,0]`. Now **increase the last dimension only by *its* stride amount**, giving you `[1,0,1]`. Keep doing this until you reach the limit. Something like `[1,0,2]`, `[1,0,3]` (end of the loop). Now in your next iteration, start by incrementing the second to last dimension and resetting the last dimension, `[1,1,0]`. Here the second to last dimension is equal to `end[1]`, so move to the first dimension (third to last) and reset the rest, giving you `[2,0,0]`. Again you are at the first dimension's limit, so quit the loop.

The following code is a recursive implementation of what I described above,

```
# Assume global `begin`, `end` and `stride`
def iterate(active, dim):
    if dim == len(begin):
        # last dimension incremented, work on the new matrix
        # Note that `active` and `begin` are lists
        new_matrix[active - begin] = old_matrix[active]
    else:
        for i in range(begin[dim], end[dim], stride[dim]):
            new_active = copy(active)
            new_active[dim] = i
            iterate(new_active, dim + 1)

iterate(begin, 0)
```

Comment: but `[1, 1, 0]` returns `4` rather than `3`?

Comment: Hi. I understand how this part works "increase the last dimension only by its stride amount", but how do I get [[[3, 3, 3]]] in the end? Could you please be a little more clear? Thanks @martianwars

Answer (score 25):

I experimented a bit with this method, which gave me some insights, which I think might be of some use. let's say we have a tensor.

```py
a = np.array([[[1, 1.2, 1.3], [2, 2.2, 2.3], [7, 7.2, 7.3]],
              [[3, 3.2, 3.3], [4, 4.2, 4.3], [8, 8.2, 8.3]],
              [[5, 5.2, 5.3], [6, 6.2, 6.3], [9, 9.2, 9.3]]]) 
# a.shape = (3, 3, 3)
```

`strided_slice()` requires 4 required arguments `input_, begin, end, strides` in which we are giving our `a` as `input_` argument.
 As the case with `tf.slice()` method, the `begin` argument is zero-based and rest of args shape-based.  **However in the docs `begin` and `end` both are zero-based**.

The functionality of method is quite simple: 
It works like iterating over a loop, where `begin` is the location of element in the tensor from where the loop initiates and `end` is where it stops.

```py
tf.strided_slice(a, [0, 0, 0], [3, 3, 3], [1, 1, 1])

# output =  the tensor itself

tf.strided_slice(a, [0, 0, 0], [3, 3, 3], [2, 2, 2])

# output = [[[ 1.   1.3]
#            [ 7.   7.3]]
#           [[ 5.   5.3]
#            [ 9.   9.3]]]
```

`strides` are like steps over which the loop iterates, here the `[2,2,2]` makes method to produce values starting at (0,0,0), (0,0,2), (0,2,0), (0,2,2), (2,0,0), (2,0,2) ..... in the `a` tensor.

```py
tf.strided_slice(input3, [1, 1, 0], [2, -1, 3], [1, 1, 1])
```

will produce output similar to `tf.strided_slice(input3, [1, 1, 0], [2, 2, 3], [1, 1, 1])` as the tensor`a` has `shape = (3,3,3)`.

Comment: that's' really helpful!

Answer (score 14):

The conceptualization that really helped me understand this was that this function emulates the indexing behavior of numpy arrays.

If you're familiar with numpy arrays, you'll know that you can make slices via `input[start1:end1:step1, start2:end2:step2, ... startN:endN:stepN]`. Basically, a very succinct way of writing `for` loops to get certain elements of the array.

(If you're familiar with python indexing, you know that you can grab an array slice via `input[start:end:step]`. Numpy arrays, which may be nested, make use of the above tuple of slice objects.)

Well, `strided_slice` just allows you to do this fancy indexing without the syntactic sugar. The numpy example from above just becomes

```
# input[start1:end1:step1, start2:end2:step2, ... startN:endN:stepN]
tf.strided_slice(input, [start1, start2, ..., startN],
    [end1, end2, ..., endN], [step1, step2, ..., stepN])
```

The documentation is a bit confusing about this in the sense that:

**a) `begin` - `end` is not strictly the shape of the return value**:

The documentation claims otherwise, but this is only true if your strides are all ones.
Examples:

```
rank1 = tf.constant(list(range(10)))
# The below op is basically:
# rank1[1:10:2] => [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
tf.strided_slice(rank1, [1], [10], [2])

# [10,10] grid of the numbers from 0 to 99
rank2 = tf.constant([[i+j*10 for i in range(10)] for j in range(10)])
# The below op is basically:
# rank2[3:7:1, 5:10:2] => numbers 30 - 69, ending in 5, 7, or 9
sliced = tf.strided_slice(rank2, [3, 5], [7, 10], [1, 2])
# The below op is basically:
# rank2[3:7:1] => numbers 30 - 69
sliced = tf.strided_slice(rank2, [3], [7], [1])
```

**b) it states that "`begin`, `end`, and `strides` will be all length n, where n is in general not the same dimensionality as `input`"**

It sounds like dimensionality means rank here - but `input` *does* have to be a tensor of at least rank-n; it can't be lower (see rank-2 example above).

N.B. I've said nothing/not really explored the masking feature, but that seems beyond the scope of the question.

Answer (score 2):

tf.strided_slice() is used to do numpy style slicing of a tensor variable.
It has 4 parameters in general: input, begin, end, strides.The slice continues by adding stride to the begin index until all dimensions are not less than the end. For ex: 
Let us take a tensor constant named "sample" of dimensions: [3,2,3]

```
import tensorflow as tf 

sample = tf.constant(
    [[[11, 12, 13], [21, 22, 23]],
    [[31, 32, 33], [41, 42, 43]],
    [[51, 52, 53], [61, 62, 63]]])

slice = tf.strided_slice(sample, begin=[0,0,0], end=[3,2,3], strides=[2,2,2])

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(slice))
```

Now, the output will be:

```
[[[11 13]]

 [[51 53]]]
```

This is because the striding starts from [0,0,0] and goes to [2,1,2] discarding any non-existent data like:

```
[[0,0,0], [0,0,2], [0,2,0], [0,2,2],
[2,0,0], [2,0,2], [2,2,0], [2,2,2]]
```

If you use [1,1,1] as strides then it will simply print all the values.

Answer (score 0):

I find this technique useful to debug the solution.
rule: always omit recurring patterns and try to keep step at `(end-1)`.

```
t = tf.constant([[[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2]],
             [[3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4]],
             [[5, 5, 5], [6, 6, 6]]])  

# ex 1:
tf.strided_slice(t, [1, 0, 0], [2, 1, 3], [1, 1, 1])

# 3rd position:
1,0,0 > 3     
1,0,1 > 3
1,0,2 > 3
# 2nd and 1st position:satisfies the rule listed above, skipping these.

# ex 2:
tf.strided_slice(t, [1, 0, 0], [2, 2, 3], [1, 1, 1])

# 3rd position:
1,0,0 > 3     
1,0,1 > 3
1,0,2 > 3
# 2nd positon:
1,1,0 > 4
1,1,1 > 4
1,1,2 > 4
# 1st position: satisfies the rule listed above, skipping.

# Ex 3:
tf.strided_slice(t, [1, -1, 0], [2, -3, 3], [1, -1, 1])

# 3rd position:
1,-1,0 > 4
1,-1,1 > 4
1,-1,2 > 4
# 2nd position:
1,-2,0 > 3
1,-2,1 > 3
1,-2,2 > 3
# 1st position:satisfies the rule listed above, skipping.
```