# Tensorflow slice operator to strided_slice

Tags: python, tensorflow

I would like to access the first channel of a tensor, which has a shape of: `[batch_size, img_width, img_height, channel_size]`

Currently I do it like this:

```
ch1 = X[...,0]
```

But I would like to give this operation a name, so I have to use [`tf.strided_slice`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/strided_slice), but I can not really understand how that works. How is it possible to rewrite `X[...,0]` using `tf.strided_slice`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does \`tf.strided\_slice()\` do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41380126/what-does-tf-strided-slice-do)

Answer (score 0):

`tf.strided_slice(ch1,[0,0,0,0],[batch_size, img_width, img_height,1])`

You'll need to use `tf.reshape` to get exact same shape returned by `X[...,0]`.